# Cannot push to openshift git remote

Tags: git, ssh, openshift, atlassian-sourcetree

I cannot push or  pull from my remote, using sourcetree, ssh://5501b0c04382ecfefe0000a2@node-xxx.rhcloud.com/~/git/node.git, I get the error.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags openshift master:master
Pushing to ssh://5501b0c04382ecfefe0000a2@node-xxx.rhcloud.com/~/git/node.git/

fatal: '~/git/node.git/' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can rhc ssh into my app no problems, and have my key uploaded to my account and also in my .ssh folder. I have the key active in my Putty Pageant. Can you please tell me how I can push to remote?

Many thanks

Comment: Is that your repository? Or should you be pushing to a fork?

Comment: Yes its my git repo, trying to push master

Comment: Can you `git clone` it? I have experienced git related errors with openshift and doing fresh clone always helped. `rhc git-clone -a node`

Comment: Thanks, had to recreate the app in the end and worked fine.